# Why am I seeing "Resource has been exhausted" when I make 6 requests per day?

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client

I'm using the Google API Client (PHP) to read a Google Sheet ~6 times per day, spaced out at least one hour apart. Twice in the last couple of weeks I've had this response:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 429,
    "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "rateLimitExceeded"
      }
    ],
    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
  }
}
```

It seems highly unlikely that this is the actual cause.

Looking at the quotas/requests:

[image: requests per day]

[image: requests per minute]

[image: limits]

[image: quotas]

Google System status says everything's OK. They point you here for technical questions and seem to make it particularly difficult to ask anybody - so here I am.

Why am I seeing this, or is it just a glitch?

Comment: I am wondering how the quota page looks, where you can see the ones are nearby the limit, try to open this link https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas and if you can verify the read request. I also had a similar issue in the past and would like to give you some insight about the matter.

Comment: I have updated my question with a screenshot from that quota page. My understanding is we are looking at tiny numbers well within limits.

Comment: That is correct, at least during these couple of days, however there was an instance where you reach the peak usage of the read request per minute. That could help you to start the process for quota increase from my response.

Comment: It's not possible to exceed the limit with one read request every hour. It must be a glitch with the API since nothing has changed on my side and I've not seen the behaviour before or since.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea to run the same script that you have under a copy of the Sheet or a new Sheet to verify it. I had similar issues and it might not be a direct glitch, more like a cache of the Sheet itself, where a particular formula or functions that I have on the Sheet is not working properly, due to the amount of data over the Sheet. Check if the Sheet is having some issues when opened over the browser.

It is a very common error that has been fully documented over this help center [article](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) with a couple of suggestions on what can be done like an exponential backoff.

Also review my suggestion from the comments on how to properly review the quota usage and percentage of the day or week. There are other limits that have not been from Google, which is why it could be a good idea to test it with a new Sheet.